# Can I use SSL cert to encrypt SAML2 responses?

Tags: iis, ssl

We have a website hosted in IIS 7.5, say www.example.com, and we purchased an SSL cert for it. Now we would like to implement SAML2.0 in some of the responses. Is it possible to use our existing SSL cert to encrypt the SAML responses?

Answer (score 0):

As trust is negotiated by swapping metadata (i. e. an XML file containing among other things public key and certificate of a peer) at setup time, any SSL certificate should be sufficient. Even a self signed cert is usable for this task.